# Material UI styles not working in component (warning: several instances of `@material-ui/styles`)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I've created a stand-alone React component that uses the Material UI (4.8.3) library and published this to a private NPM package in order that it can be used in a range of apps.

The stand-alone component project works fine (I'm using Storybook to test the component), but when I publish and then import the component into a new React project (created using create-react-app) I get the warning:

```
It looks like there are several instances of `@material-ui/styles` initialized in this application. This may cause theme propagation issues, broken class names, specificity issues, and makes your application bigger without a good reason.
```

The component renders on the page as seen below, but without any theming applied:

[image: Component before click]

When it is clicked, any theming on the main React App is removed (note the dark blue bar in the background behind the menu has lost its color):

[image: Component after click]

I'm using the Material UI `withStyles` functionality to theme my component, which I guess is the problem as my main React app is also using this, but this is the recommended way to apply to style. Does it feel like I need to somehow inherit an instance of the theme from the main host App?

My component project was created using create-react-library and so is using Rollup (0.64.1) and babel (6.26.3).

Here is the component:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

const styles = theme => ({
    root: {
        fontSize: '14px',
    }
})

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class MyComponent extends Component {

    render() {
        const { classes } = this.props

        return (
            <div className={classes.root}>Hello world</div>
        )
    }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(MyComponent)
```

Which is published to an NPM package and then imported into the main app using:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { MyComponent } from '@xxx/mycomponent'

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    flexGrow: 1
  }
});

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Class
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class App extends Component {
  //

  // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  render() {
    //
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <MyComponent />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(withStyles(styles)(App))
```

Comment: Your question needs more clarification, please leave some codes or link a CodeSandBox reproduction of your issue.

Comment: Hi. I’ve added the code, but it’s pretty basic.

Comment: Any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but I do not use StoryBook. This is the first link in Google, so I post my case here, as it might help.

[This is the link on how to fix the alert](https://material-ui.com/getting-started/faq/#i-have-several-instances-of-styles-on-the-page), but it does not work for me. `npm dedupe` does nothing and I am unable to change config since I am using create-react-app.

So I did following:

1. Removed @material-ui/styles dependency from *package.json*
2. Ran `npm i`
3. Changed all `import styles from '@material-ui/styles'` to `import styles from '@material-ui/core/styles'`

Answer (score 1):

I have an almost identical setup and ran into this exact issue when importing the components into a different project. I should mention that we're using webpack to build the app that's consuming the component. It was suggested to me to try the following in my  webpackconfig:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@material-ui/styles": require.resolve("@material-ui/styles")
    }
  }
}
```

This worked great for my case.

For reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/

Answer (score 0):

You should link  @material-ui/styles in your story book
so first need to `npm link @material-ui/styles` in your story book and than in your apps

Answer (score 0):

Please try to install the below package. This helped resolve my issue.

```
npm i @mui/material
```